# Using components from all-in-one with broken screen

Tags: motherboard, case, enclosure

I have a Lenovo all in one A340-24ICB with a broken screen.

Is it possible to build a working system with an external monitor:

1 - Transplant the motherboard into a new case. Is there a suitable case that fits this motherboard?

2 - Buy a case and motherboard that can accept the Intel i3-9100T and memory. Is there a suggested case and motherboard for this?

Comment: The motherboard in an all-in-one will not be compatible with any case you can buy so your best chances are taking the CPU, RAM, & drive out of that all-in-one and using them with a new motherboard. The RAM might be the notebook SODIMM size too, which is not going to work in most LGA1151 motherboards.

Comment: Hi Romen, thanks for your reply. Yes, I've checked and you are correct, I think I need an Intel 300 series motherboard with SODIMM which seem to be almost not existent.

Comment: Your devices does seem to have an external display output. If you connect a display there - do you get an output?
If so, you could always have a "case" / motherboard mount 3D-printed for the mainboard.

Comment: Thanks @towe, yeah I'm thinking the most viable option could be to build a case out of wood or acrylic and use some of the original chassis to mount the motherboard.